# User id and databases php sql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make a page where a logged in user can create a post-it  note, and add it to the "post-it wall" Im using 3 tables in my database for this [One table for the post-it data, one for the post-it colors and a user table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJxeE.png)

My problem is that i cant figure out how i can store the id from the user in the postit users_id table so that it only can be the user that created the post-it that can delete it again. Any tips?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the user id as a session and then call that variable from the session when inserting/updating/selecting?

```
<?php
session_start();

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["user_id"] = "mysql result for id here"; //$result['user_id']
```

Comment: Im sorry, i just started learning PHP last week, how do i do this

Comment: I See thanks, and now somehow i got to implement that so it remembers that for example user with id 1 created for example post-it with id 4 when the user creates a post it

Comment: Not sure if I understand your last comment. Basically, when you have PHP check mysql database when logging in as the user based on username and password matching, you can have something like $result = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$_POST['username'] AND password=$_POST['password']"); and then you can do $_SESSION["user_id"] = $result['user_id'];      also, my code is not best practice as you should be hashing or encoding your password before checking the database to match and also my code is vulnerable to SQL injection. was just using this as basic example.

Comment: @Marz_89 Giving quick advice like that is extremely risky. It's akin to saying "Open-heart surgery is easy, just remember to wash your hands and don't cut anything important, lol!"

Comment: @tadman yeah I am aware, he is new to learning and clearly this is not for production use so they will learn about SQL Injection later on, just trying to give him a basic example of one of many ways to do this.

Comment: This is not how people learn. This is how businesses get destroyed, information gets compromised, and careers come to an abrupt halt. You learn about SQL injection *first* before you do any damage. Safety is not some academic concern. It's an absolute must in the hostile environment that is today's public internet. Please don't say "you can fix this later" because once your site is attacked there's no do-overs, you're done.

Comment: @tadman now you're just being pompous. I gave a basic answer for a basic question. I am not going to sit here and teach someone about the rights and wrongs of programming when that is not what the question asked. Nor am I going to mark this as a duplicate answer or state that they need to do more research like everyone else on this website... you'll live and so will he.

Comment: If you could deploy vulnerable code and there were no risks then I wouldn't be here arguing about this. That's not the case. The PHP community has a lot of historical baggage to deal with and not caring the least bit about even the most basic database sanitization principles is one of the most serious concerns. Don't be a part of the problem is all I'm saying.

Comment: @tadman I understand your concern. Would it not have been easier to suggest your own answer along with sanitized code?

Comment: You took the initiative, so I usually let people fix up their code before going down that road and stealing the green check mark away. Normally you can express the query in a form with `?` placeholders already present and defer to PDO vs. `mysqli` vs. some other database driver to populate those correctly.